# Other way than pivot table - Incrementation

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pivot

I'm working on a very simple database but I don't know if pivot table is a good solution for it. If I use pivot table, I need to add useless table just for incrementation.

Let's start from the beginning.

During user registration, a new table GROUP is created. In GROUP table we have registered user_id and group_id. This table allow / reject acces to folders.

This user can add to his group others users (Same group_id).

My issue:

I don't want to use pivot table because I need another table for it and it's useless because I don't need to set a name etc for group. I can't also use incrementation because I can't repeat the same number (group_id).

First schema:
[image]

Second schema (Pivot)
[image]

Comment: Make life easier don't use reserved words as table names.

Comment: I have no idea what this question is about and cannot acces the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to reprensent the relation between users and groups in your database ?

The answer to this depends on how the relationship is modeled :

- if a user may belong to just one group, or each group contains just one user, then you have a 1-N relationship ; you can store the information as an additional column in (respectively) table `user` or table `group`
- if a group can contain multiple users, and a user may belong to multiple groups, then you have a N-M relationship ; the proper way to represent it is to create a bridge table (which you called pivot table), where each record stores a foreign key to the bridge and a foreign key to the user table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using the term "pivot table" correctly. At least not the way other people use that term.

It looks like you just need a many-to-many relationship between users and groups. You may think you don't need a table for `group` because you don't need a name or other properties for the group.

But consider: You have a foreign key in your `folder` table that references a group id. Which row in your `user_group` table should that reference? There will be many rows in that table for a given group id. A foreign key should reference a PRIMARY KEY of the referenced table.